# Shiny R ColVis Extension: Group Columns

Tags: r, datatables, shiny

I was wondering if it is possible to show/hide group columns? I have seen it is possible in Datatables.net but I do not know how to do it in Shiny R.

Also, is it possible to initialize a column to be hidden by the time you run the app?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the first question, but having some columns hidden when you initialize is possible

```
  idx <- 1:2
  DT::datatable(...
                options = list(
                  columnDefs = list(list(visible = FALSE,
                                         targets = idx))
                )
  )
```

Please see http://rstudio.github.io/DT/ for more information about the **DT** package.